# Monoidal structures on modules over derived coalgebras

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory, operads, coalgebras

Given a Hopf-algebra $H$ (over a commutative ring), it is a classical fact that its category of (left) modules is monoidal, even if $H$ is not commutative. Given two left modules $M$ and $N$, we can form a new left module structure on $M\otimes N$ via the structure map $$H\otimes M\otimes N\overset{\Delta\otimes 1\otimes 1}\to H\otimes H\otimes M\otimes N\overset{1\otimes\tau\otimes 1}\to H\otimes M\otimes H \otimes N\to M\otimes N.$$

When working in a derived setting (let's assume $H$ is an object in a symmetric monoidal quasicategory $\mathscr{C}$), things can be slightly more complicated, and we should probably have $H$ with monoidal structure and comonoidal structure given by some operads like the little $n$-disk operads $\mathbb{E}_n.$ It's basically formal when working in quasicategories to say that $H$ is an $\mathbb{E}_n$-algebra with a compatible $\mathbb{E}_m$-coalgebra structure, making it into an $\mathbb{E}_n/\mathbb{E}_m$-bialgebra in $\mathscr{C}$. We just say that $H$ is an $\mathbb{E}_n$-algebra object in the quasicategory of $\mathbb{E}_m$-coalgebra objects in $\mathscr{C}$.

It's known that, in general, given an $\mathbb{E}_n$-algebra, the category of left modules over it is $\mathbb{E}_{n-1}$-monoidal. This is why, for instance, left modules over a noncommutative ring (i.e. an $\mathbb{E}_1$-algebra) are not monoidal at all. So my question is, to what extent can we perform the above trick in a "derived" way? Obviously it does not suffice to simply write down the structure map, since we need a whole lot of coherent data to write down a module structure now, but is there some other way to do it?

A good example would be, I think, the example of an $n$-fold loop space $X$. Any space, via the diagonal map, is an $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-coalgebra. In fact there's an equivalence of quasicategories $CoAlg_{\mathbb{E}_\infty}(Top)\simeq Top$. So an $n$-fold loop space is definitely an $\mathbb{E}_n$-algebra in $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-coalgebras in $Top$. So, is the category of modules in $Top$ over $X$ somehow "more monoidal than it should be?" In general, how well does this type of thing work?

Comment: Are precise compatibility conditions for E$_n$-algebra and E$_m$-coalgebra structures worked out somewhere?

Comment: I remember trying this and it was a mess - if you cap an upwards growing tree with an upside-down one, you get more or less arbitrary graph, i.e. something not contractible; how to "disentangle" it was not clear to me

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე compatibility conditions are NOT worked out anywhere. the best I can do is what I said above, but writing down what that means geometrically or combinatorially seems like an unbelievable mess.

Comment: I see :( The A$_\infty$ case is, I believe, worked out by Saneblidze and Umble...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე ah, I wasn't familiar with that, maybe I'll check it out.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე there are also, if I understand correctly, properads and $\infty$-properads for bialgebras, which might be slightly more general. I am just not aware of anyone doing this for $E_n$.

Comment: Well afaik even a good description of the plain ordinary Hopf algebra (as opposed to bialgebra) PROP is not known

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I am inclined to believe that one cannot have a Hopf-algebra PROP, in the same way that one cannot have an operad for groups, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Have you seen work of Mesablishvili and Wisbauer? It gives some hope: they manage to get rid of the antipode, similarly in spirit to as Freyd manages to describe additive categories "from inside" abelian semigroup enriched categories by requiring upper triangular endomorphisms to be automorphisms...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81982/discussion-between-jonathan-beardsley-and--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't make the above answer work, so here's an approach explained to me by Rune Haugseng (of course any errors are entirely my own). Let $C$ be symmetric monoidal and $p\colon C^\otimes\to Fin_\ast$ be the cocartesian fibration witnessing this. First notice that $CoAlg(C)^{op}\simeq Alg(C^{op})$ has a "pointwise" symmetric monoidal structure which is given by [HA.3.2.4.3](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf#page=370), and therefore $CoAlg(C)$ also has a symmetric monoidal structure i.e. there is a cocartesian fibration $q\colon CoAlg(C)^\otimes\to Fin_\ast$. Here I'm using the fact that $C^{op}$ has a symmetric monoidal structure induced by taking the fiberwise dual of $p$ in the sense of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2165.pdf). Similar considerations give a symmetric monoidal structure to $LCoMod(C)\simeq LMod(C^{op})^{op}$. Moreover, there is a cartesian fibration $LMod(C^{op})\to Alg(C^{op})$ by [HA.4.2.3.2](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf#page=527) which gives a fiberwise cartesian fibration $LMod(C^{op})^\otimes\to Alg(C^{op})^\otimes$. By taking fiberwise duals again we get a fiberwise cocartesian fibration $LCoMod(C)^\otimes\to CoAlg(C)^\otimes$. It's a little tricky, but one can check that this fiberwise cocartesian fibration satisfies the condition A.1.8 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.11312.pdf#page=40) and is therefore a cocartesian fibration. On a fixed fiber this says that if I've got a map of coalgebras $A\to B$ (or a finite list of maps of coalgebras) then I get a left adjoint functor $LCoMod_A(C)\to LCoMod_B(C)$ which takes the coaction $M\to A\otimes M$ to $M\to A\otimes M\to B\otimes M$ (this is the "opposite" of restriction of scalars). But now we've lifted it up to $LCoMod(C)^\otimes\to CoAlg(C)^\otimes$ so that it plays well with the monoidal structure, which we'll need.

Now suppose that $H$ is a bialgebra in $C$, i.e. $H$ is an algebra object in $CoAlg(C)\simeq Alg(C^{op})^{op}$ .  In other words, $H$ is determined by a functor of $\infty$-operads $H^\otimes\colon Assoc^\otimes\to CoAlg(C)^\otimes$. Then we can pull back the cocartesian fibration $LCoMod(C)^\otimes\to CoAlg(C)^\otimes$ along $H^\otimes$ to obtain a cocartesian fibration $LCoMod_H(C)^\otimes\to Assoc^\otimes$. There's a little bit of checking to do if you want to make sure that this pullback really is equivalent to $LCoMod_H(C)^n$ over each $\langle n\rangle\in Assoc^\otimes$, but it's not too bad.

I should add that you can fully analyze the cocartesian morphisms in $LCoMod_H(C)^\otimes$ and check that the $H$-coaction on the tensor product of two $H$-comodules $M$ and $N$ is indeed $M\otimes N\to M\otimes H\otimes N\otimes H\to M\otimes N\otimes H\otimes H\to M\otimes N\otimes H$.

Answer (score 5):

Not quite sure what your exact question is, but the general pattern is as follows: let $Pr$ be the $(\infty,1)$-symmetric monoidal category of presentable categories, cocontinuous functors, natural isos between them and so on. Let $S\in E_\infty-alg(Pr)$ be a presnetable symmetric monoidal category. Then you have a symmetric monoidal functors
$$E_1-alg(S)\longrightarrow Pr$$
sending $A$ to $A-mod$ and a morphism $A\rightarrow B$ to the corresponding induction functor $-\otimes_A B$. Likewise you have a symmetric monoidal functor
$$E_1-coalg(S)\longrightarrow Pr$$
sending $C$ to $C-comod$ and a morphism $C\rightarrow D$ to corestriction. Therefore you get a functor
$$E_1-bialg(S)=E_1-alg(E_1-coalg(S))\longrightarrow E_1-alg(Pr)$$
by applying "comod", hence the category of comodules over a bialgebra is $E_1$, i.e. monoidal. Likewise, modules over a bialgebra should really be regarded as a "comonoidal category", i.e. an $E_1$-coalgebra in $Pr$. It is also monoidal basically because restriction along algebra morphisms is also cocontinuous, i.e. there is also a contravariant functor from $E_1-alg(S)$ to $Pr$, but this is somewhat less natural and leads to some techincal issues (already in the classical/non-derived case).

Now applying Dunn's theorem you get similar statements for the higer versions of bialgebras.

Comment: I was just coming back to this (2 years later!) and wondering if you knew how precisely to get that functor Coalg(S)→Pr. I found the relevant functor in for Alg in higher algebra.